# Поведение Activity при нажатии кнопки home

Tags: android

После сворачивания приложения, через некоторое время(или если открыть много всего) запускаю приложение, запускается активити, которое в топе таска и начинает выполнять код из onCreate(), но данные активити получает из нижних активити, собственно они равны null и приложение падает или некорректно работает! Как сделать так, что бы при простое в фоне, приложение запускалось с корневого активити, но при недолгом сворачивании нормально открывалось!

Comment: onPause, onResume ?

Comment: Что вы предлагаете?

Comment: сохранять эти данные в преференсах

Comment: Я предлагаю переопределить эти методы и cохранять там данные которые нужны будут для восстановления

Comment: @Чад, мне не нужно, сохранять и восстанавливать! Таск должен очищаться при простое и загружаться корневое активити, а загружается последнее!

Comment: ну так правильно все, сохранять в преференсах нужные параметры

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение, не знаю насколько оно безопасное и правильное

после

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

вставил

```
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        finish();
    }
```

И теперь все работает как нужно

Answer (score 2):

Прибивайте активити, когда onPause ?

```
 function void onPause(...) { finish(); }
```

Comment: Это то очевидно! Но если пользователь свернет приложение, активити разрушиться! 
Вопрос был такой: "Как сделать так, что бы при простое в фоне, приложение запускалось с корневого активити, но при недолгом сворачивании нормально открывалось!" 
По идее приложение не должно так себя вести, по умолчанию должен таск очищаться! Может я где то намудрил!

Comment: Ну повестись тогда на onDestroy?

Comment: @Чад, мне кажется бессмыслено разрушать активити, переопределив метод разрушения активити! Хотя кто его знает, попробую!

Comment: @katso, ну вы дополнительно проверочку поставьте естественно - что дестрой не вы вызвали, а система. Но Вообще наверное ещё решением может быть на onResume повесить проверку - если данные убиты - то finish()

Comment: Хотя наверное да, вешайтесь на onStop а не на onDestroy. В любом случае Вам надо логику отката к главному активити прописывать. А не надеяться на волшебство